# Get just the url of attachment javamail api?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-mail, attachment

I want to save the url of attachment into mysql database in order to download it from mobile client (iphone) when user demand downloading attachment.

```
 String disposition = part.getDisposition();
               if (disposition != null && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase("ATTACHMENT")))  
                  // mail have attachment
```

I'm using this code to get the part of the message which is an attachment.
But i can't get it's url.
Any idea?

Comment: There is no URL for an attachment: the attachment is an integral part of the mailmessage.

Comment: But if I download the attachment with Internet Download Manager it shows an url. here is an example : https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=5e01a8ca10&view=att&th=13c431079bcfb8f6&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_haob2dho0&zw&saduie=AG9B_P-4AvB7UthDtvz9F6TfZ0If&sadet=1367062666690&sads=O79jVi_PMstR6kmTmPTTwRg99O8

Comment: That is if you download it directly from the gmail page; it doesn't work the same if you use IMAP.

Comment: I want to save just these URLs int the DB not all the attachments because the DB will save the content of many email accounts and I don't want to make it bigger. How can do this?

Comment: You cannot do that with JavaMail.

Comment: Is there any solution to save a reference on the attachment or some thing like that?

Comment: You need a program running on a web server or application server that responds to a URL request by accessing the mail server and fetching the appropriate data.

Comment: Thanks for responding but,
Can u give me more hints? I can't get your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try a url for attachment approach. For your attachments to have a url, you need a server that will hold all attachments, and you will to embed the url to an attachment in theemail, before it is sent out.. which can only be possible if te email is sent from your sysem.

You should instead look at it like asking a user before loading the attachment part of the message. If the user says yes, load the whole email, including the attachment.